# Add the Consecutive Days calendar to Area 51

Tags: feature-request, area-51, consecutive-days, visited-days

On Area 51's profile site, the visited days are correctly displayed. However, I have grown accustomed to having the ability to click on the link and be able to see the days that I have visited. On Stack Overflow, I get

[image: a calendar that highlights all of the days that I have come to the site]

But the consecutive days text on Area 51 is not clickable, and thus I cannot access any calendar.

Comment: That's supposed to be a hidden feature!

Comment: Area 51 is separate codebase from the Q&A sites and we'll look at adding this feature there.

Comment: So it isn't a bug?

Comment: No, not a bug, just a hidden feature that never was added to Area 51's user page. I'm going to have to blame [Emmett](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/144066/emmett), who did most of the work on Area 51 :)